# What data structure will be better fit - heap or sorted array?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl

I have a program that:

1. load some data from disk into `std::map` in memory. `std::map` keeps the data sorted.
2. save sorted data to disk

**I am wondering if heap will be faster if I do this:**

1. load some data from disk into `std::vector` in memory.
2. sort the vector
3. save the data to disk

**or even using heap:**

1. load some data from disk into `std::vector` in memory.
2. make a heap in the vector
3. pop from heap and save the data to disk

What will be fastest?

Comment: `std::map` is associative, it maps one value to another. `std::vector` isn't. So it's not clear that you can just change from one to the other.

Comment: Why don't you try both and then *benchmark* it with your specific workload (using an optimised build of course)?

Comment: You can benchmark it, but I expect sorting the vector to be the fastest option.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux flat vector of pairs, sorted by key (pair.first)

Comment: Most likely, your bottleneck (performance) is writing data to the disk.  Your usage of data structures is probably negligible compared to the time spent writing to the disk.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it is toy project, I want to do it as performed as possible. Also we are speaking about 20-30 M pairs in memory. It took more time to build in memory "thing" than to write them to disk, since I write sequentialy

Comment: I put update as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Asymptotically all of your approaches are *O(n log n)*:

- Inserting an element in an `std::map` is logarithmic in the size of the container. Inserting *n* elements will be *O(n log n)*.
- Applying `std::sort` on an `std::vector` is *O(n log n)*.
- Creating a heap can be done in linear time with `std::make_heap`. However, poping an element from the heap is logarithmic in the size of the heap. Poping *n* elements from the heap is *O(n log n)*.

However, I expect the approaches consisting of sorting the `std::vector` and the heap to be faster than the one with the `std::map` since they take more advantage of the cache thanks to better data locality, i.e., the elements in these two cases consist of *contiguously* allocated blocks in memory rather than nodes spread out in memory as with the `std::map`.

Note also that the approach with the `std::map` requires more space than the other two because of the pointers that glue the map's nodes together.

Comment: My thoughts indeed. Also map waste much more memory than you can imagine. Of course it gives you ordering while inserting, but I do not really need it.

Answer (score 1):

I want to share some tests.

In both cases I use my custom allocator, so I can check how much memory actually is in use.

However my custom allocator does not work with the vector, so internal vector memory is not calculated (8 bytes per record) also allocation is pass to standard allocator (`operator new` / `malloc`).

I do not reserve the vector in front, because I do not know how many records there will be.

## Conclusion

**Vector is faster and uses way less memory!**

---

**Standard implementation** using STL-like skiplist - it is 4-5% slower than `std::map`, but uses way less memory.

```
Processed    9940000 records. In memory    9940000 records,  310162322 bytes. Allocator  663018328 bytes.
Processed    9950000 records. In memory    9950000 records,  310477634 bytes. Allocator  663688048 bytes.
Processed    9960000 records. In memory    9960000 records,  310793005 bytes. Allocator  664357320 bytes.
Processed    9970000 records. In memory    9970000 records,  311108063 bytes. Allocator  665025016 bytes.
Processed    9980000 records. In memory    9980000 records,  311422710 bytes. Allocator  665694536 bytes.
Processed    9990000 records. In memory    9990000 records,  311738268 bytes. Allocator  666363680 bytes.
Processed   10000000 records. In memory    9999999 records,  312054428 bytes. Allocator  667035168 bytes.
Flushing data... List record(s):  9999999 List size:  312054428 

real    0m35.379s
user    0m34.218s
sys 0m1.072s
```

Notice, that for 312'054'428 bytes real data, it actually use almost twice that - 667'035'168 bytes.

---

**Vector implementation** - `std::vector`, `std::sort`, `std::unique`:

```
Processed    9890000 records. In memory    9890000 records,  308578515 bytes. Allocator  343196258 bytes.
Processed    9900000 records. In memory    9900000 records,  308895613 bytes. Allocator  343548385 bytes.
Processed    9910000 records. In memory    9910000 records,  309213506 bytes. Allocator  343901119 bytes.
Processed    9920000 records. In memory    9920000 records,  309531058 bytes. Allocator  344253602 bytes.
Processed    9930000 records. In memory    9930000 records,  309848406 bytes. Allocator  344605762 bytes.
Processed    9940000 records. In memory    9940000 records,  310162322 bytes. Allocator  344954565 bytes.
Processed    9950000 records. In memory    9950000 records,  310477634 bytes. Allocator  345304978 bytes.
Processed    9960000 records. In memory    9960000 records,  310793005 bytes. Allocator  345655307 bytes.
Processed    9970000 records. In memory    9970000 records,  311108063 bytes. Allocator  346005229 bytes.
Processed    9980000 records. In memory    9980000 records,  311422710 bytes. Allocator  346355138 bytes.
Processed    9990000 records. In memory    9990000 records,  311738268 bytes. Allocator  346705788 bytes.
Processed   10000000 records. In memory    9999999 records,  312054428 bytes. Allocator  347057202 bytes.
Flushing data... List record(s):  9999999 List size:  312054428 

real    0m12.759s
user    0m11.929s
sys 0m0.791s
```

---

Test with 80 M pairs:

2:08 vs 6:17